# Dinamic headers in Retrofit (1-2) do not work

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

I'm trying to make authtoken **GET** request to my server.
I'm trying to do in like this:

```
public interface FixedRecApi {


    public static final String ENDPOINT = "http://******.pythonanywhere.com/";

    //@Headers("Authorization: Token ce7950e8d0c266986b7f972407db898810322***") this thing work well!!
    @GET("/auth/me/")
    Observable<User> me(@Header("Authorization: Token") String token); //this does not work at all!
    Observable<User> me();


}
```

So as you see, the line with explicit header: @Headers - works perfect.
But when I try to pass it as a parameter - it says "no credentials provided".
My application onCreate:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

                .baseUrl(FixedRecApi.ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(
                        GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder()
                                .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC)
                                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                                .serializeNulls()
                .create()))
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(FixedRecApi.class);

    }
```

Have no idea what is wrong with this thing. Interceptors don't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. Headers consist of two parts:

1. header name: "Authrorization"
2. then colon
3. header value: "Token ce7950e8d0c266986b7f972407db898810322***"

So, Retrofit usage should be:

```
Observable<User> me(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

and then for example in MainActivity:

```
RetrofitApi.me("Token " + "ce7950e8d0c266986b7f972407db898810322***");
```